# Vue Router Scroll Up to Anchor

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I have followed a few post on SO on how to scroll to anchor and have the following code added:

```
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createRouter, createMemoryHistory, createWebHistory, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Router instance.
 */

export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {

  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : (process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history' ? createWebHistory : createWebHashHistory)

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) { 
      if (to && to.hash) {
        return {
            el: to.hash,
            top: 75, // avoid blocking the view when having fixed components
            behavior: 'smooth'
        };
      } else if (savedPosition) {
          return savedPosition;
      } else {
          return { top: 75 };
      }
    },
    routes,

    // Leave this as is and make changes in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE)
  })

  return Router
})
```

This works if you are already above the anchor and it will scroll down nice and clean to the anchor. However, say you are past the anchor and you click my navigation button it will not scroll up but instead resets to the top of the page then scrolls down. Just does not feel fluent. So can Vue-Router not scroll up to the anchor? My sidebar menu with router-links is as follows:

```
    <template>
    <div class="navigation-links q-pa-lg">
      <q-list padding>
        <q-item clickable v-ripple class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" 
                :to="{name: 'Home', hash: '#Home'}"
                :active="(route.name === 'Home' && route.hash === '#Home') || (route.name === 'Home' && route.hash === '')"
                active-class="active-menu-item">
          <q-item-section avatar>
            <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-house" style="font-size:1.25rem"/>
          </q-item-section>
          <q-item-section>
             HOME
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>

        <q-item clickable v-ripple class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" 
              :to="{name: 'Home', hash: '#Services'}"
              :active="route.name === 'Home' && route.hash === '#Services'"
              active-class="active-menu-item">
          <q-item-section avatar>
            <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-shirt" style="font-size:1.25rem"/>
          </q-item-section>
          <q-item-section>
            SERVICES
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>

        <q-item clickable v-ripple class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" 
              :to="{name: 'Home', hash: '#OurTeam'}"
              :active="route.name === 'Home' && route.hash === '#OurTeam'"
              active-class="active-menu-item">
          <q-item-section avatar>
            <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-users" style="font-size:1.25rem"/>
          </q-item-section>
          <q-item-section>
            OUR TEAM
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>

        <q-item clickable v-ripple class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" @click="layoutStore.toggleContactUsDrawer">
          <q-item-section avatar>
            <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-envelope" style="font-size:1.25rem"/>
          </q-item-section>
          <q-item-section>
            CONTACT US
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </div>
    <div class="socialmedia-links q-pa-lg text-center column no-wrap flex-center self" style="">
      <div class="row">
        <q-btn flat size="sm" color="primary" round icon="fa-brands fa-google" aria-label="google" class="float-right q-ma-sm no-shadow" @click="openInNewTab(companyGoogleLink)"/>
        <q-btn flat size="sm" color="primary" round icon="fa-brands fa-facebook-f" aria-label="facebook" class="float-right q-ma-sm no-shadow" @click="openInNewTab(companyFacebookLink)"/>
        <q-btn flat size="sm" color="primary" round icon="fa-brands fa-instagram" aria-label="instagram" class="float-right q-ma-sm no-shadow" @click="openInNewTab(companyInstagramLink)"/>
      </div>
      <h2 class="text-h5 text-weight-bolder q-mb-xs">CONNECT WITH US</h2>
      <h6 class="text-subtitle1 text-accent text-weight-normal q-my-none">If you like what you have seen so far we can guarentee you will appreciate our print quality.</h6>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import {storeToRefs} from 'pinia'
  import {useLayoutStore} from '../stores/layout-store'
  import {useCompanyInfoStore} from '../stores/company-info-store'
  import {useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
  
  //store
  const layoutStore = useLayoutStore()
  const {contactUsDrawer, navigationDrawer} = storeToRefs(layoutStore)

  const companyInfoStore = useCompanyInfoStore()
  const {companyFacebookLink, companyGoogleLink, companyInstagramLink} = storeToRefs(companyInfoStore)

  const searchText = ref('')
            
  const route = useRoute()
  const router = useRouter()

  //methods
  function openInNewTab(url) {
    window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
  }
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .block-wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .active-menu-item{
    background-color: $background-accent;
    color: $primary !important;
  }

  .menu-item{
    letter-spacing: .15rem;
    font-weight:500;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color:$dark
  }

</style>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce as far as vue-router functionality, see my [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-4h5eb5?file=src%2Flayouts%2FMainLayout.vue).  it scrolls up and down as you click between the two anchor based links.  if you can create a reproducible example it would help a lot.

Comment: Yea let me see if I can somehow get it setup in that sandbox environment like you have. Anytime I click a nav menu item it goes to the top of the page then scrolls down. I have updated my router index as shown above.

Comment: I also updated the nagivation sidebar so it reflects the current route for active item. I am looking at your example and I am not seeing any reason this would do this strange behavior of every click on the nav it it starts at top then scrolls down. Even if starting above or below the anchor always resets as if its reloading route then scrolling down to section.

Comment: So after some experimenting the scrolling works perfect if done from the footer links I added. When using the mainlayout q-drawer its causing this issue. Strange.

Comment: @yoduh so the issue is the body class gets this class when the q-drawer is set to mobile "q-body--prevent-scroll". I do not want this class to get assigned to body so I am curious is there a way to disable automatic classes or their impact like this one? I prefer to keep scrolling even on mobile because I use mobile for all views since its basically an overlay which I like.